# How to pass public variable in Remix online compiler

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, remix, arrays

Lets say I have this contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
contract TestArray {
    uint[] public original;
    uint[] public newOriginal;

    function TestArray(){
        original.push(2);
        original.push(3);
    }

    function testRemove(){
        newOriginal = remove(original, 0);
    }

    function getLength(uint[] array) constant returns(uint number){
        return array.length;
    }

    function remove(uint[] array, uint index) internal returns(uint[] value) {
        if (index >= array.length) return;

        uint[] arrayNew;
        for (uint i = index; i<array.length-1; i++){
            arrayNew[i] = array[i+1];
        }
        delete array;
        return arrayNew;
    }
}
```

How would you call `getLength` function in Remix browser by passing `newOriginal` array. I also find that there is no way in Remix to see values of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Remix, the key is to not enter a full JSON string in the field for getLength. So if you enter your array in the field like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

The call to getLength will work.

Also it looks like you can return an array from a function, but only if you remove the `internal` keyword. I was able to get your `remove()` method to work by changing the code to this:

```
function remove(uint[] array, uint index) returns(uint[] value) {
    if (index >= array.length) return;

    uint[] memory arrayNew = new uint[](array.length-1);

    for (uint i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        arrayNew[i] = array[i];    
    } 

    for (uint j = index; j<array.length-1; j++){
        uint val = array[j+1];
        arrayNew[j] = val;
    } 

    return arrayNew;
}
```